# How to fix "System.Guid is a type but used like a variable" when using "@Guid"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, guid

So I have no idea why I'm getting this issue with the Guid here.  Can anyone please lend some insight?

```
@using System;
@using AC.Common.Comparing
@using AC.Business.Object.B2BOrderHandling
@using AC.Website.Areas.OrderManagement.Views.B2BOrderHandling.App_LocalResources
@using AC.Website.Areas.OrderManagement.Models

@model ComparisonRowModel

@Guid messageID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
@string x = messageID.ToString();

<div @(Model.Current != null ? string.Format("orderdetailsid={0}", Model.Current.OrderDetailsID) : "") data-guid="@(x)" class="current menuitem @(Model.ChangeType == B2BMenuItemChangeTypeModel.Deleted ? "deleted" : "")">
@switch (Model.ChangeType)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put initialization in a code block. Then you can drop all the `@`s:

```
@{
    Guid messageID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    string x = messageID.ToString();
}
```

The [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29) is a must read.